# How could I run kubectl -k in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, kubectl, kustomize

Currently the Azure kubectl task uses Kubectl version 1.13.xxx. Is there any way to run a newer version of kubectl that supports apply -k or kustomize?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT indeed that worked like a charm. In the documentation it felt that the highest version possible is 1.13 so I did not try changing that to 1.21. I did now and it works like a charm (I was re-creating those steps manually, downloading and caching kubectl 1.21)

Comment: Glad to know that it could work. If the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it as answer, thank you.

Comment: On the other hand, you could refer to this doc :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software to confrim the pre-installed software. It contains kubectl 1.21.1

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT in this particular case I was trying that for a local agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to run a newer version of kubectl that supports apply -k or kustomize?

You could define the kubectl version in `kbectl task -> Advanced tab`.

[image]

The default value is 1.13.2, you could change it to the required version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was an option when the question was originally asked, but for anyone stumbling across this question now Azure DevOps has a special "bake" task for applying kustomize templating

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/bake?view=azure-devops#kustomize-example